# How do I change height of product list rows?

Tags: product, image, design

I was wondering if it would be possible to change the height of the rows on product list view.

I would like to make the rows 35px high, and remove the image.

Does anybody know if this is possible? URL for your reference: http://freemusicforvideos.com/music.html

I would also like to get rid of the 'Add to Cart' button, and make the next step be via clicking the product title.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to rewrite

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml.
```

Remove images from template. After you will need to change styles.